# How do I call a variable that I assigned in an if statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and I wanted to make a script that makes you calculate what your after-tax salary is. When I tried to call a variable I assigned in an if statement it said,

```
NameError: name 'bruto1' is not defined.
```

This is the code:

```
if bruto<20142 and bruto>0:
    bruto1 = (bruto*0.3655)

netto = (bruto - bruto1)
```

I already found the problem thanks to konserw

Comment: if the if statement is evaluated to `False` the variable will not exist, you can initialize it before or use an `else` block

Comment: There is no `nameofvariable` in your script.  How are we supposed to find your problem without it.

Comment: @Simon I think he was referencing to `bruto1` which is instantiated in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In an event bruto was < 0 or > 20142 you tried to access bruto1 variable that don't exist (because block in if statement wasn't executed).

You have 2 possibilities - either start with defining default value to bruto1, for example 0, so that whenever you try accessing that variable it has some value; or make sure all execution paths that are possible in your program lead to assignment of some value to that variable, for example by using if...else...

```
brutto1 = 0
if brutto < 20142 and bruto > 0:
    brutto1 = (brutto * 0.3655)

netto = (brutto - brutto1)
```

I think more pythonic way is conditional assignment to variable in one line, for example:

```
netto = (brutto - (brutto*0.3655)) if brutto < 20142 else (<place another calculation here>)
```

EDIT:
Fixed typo in variable names.

P.S. I suggest using pylint to catch such smells (or good IDE like pycharm, that would underline typos and use-before-assignment of variables)

Comment: There is no need for pre-assignation here. The only thing the OP needs to take care is if his statement is false.

Comment: @scharette - in this particular example yes, becouse of how simple it is, not necessarily true for more complex control flows. For example if there would be operation inside if or else block that can throw exception (e.x. division by 0), silenced further down the road, but skipping assignment of value to bruto1...

Comment: Also for me it's better then the same assignment in else block, but it depends on your view ;)